# Check for the existence of an ID in HTML

Tags: vba, excel

I need your help :-)

I need to check in the HTML code the existence of a tag with the "submit" ID.
I do this:

```
If Not oie.Document.getelementbyid("submit") Is Nothing Then
MsgBox oie.Document.getelementbyid("submit")
Else: MsgBox "not found"
End If
```

but such a check works properly only if the "submit" ID is in the code, and if there is not any in the code, then the error "Runtime error 424. Object required".

How can I check for the existence of the ID and make DO WHILE cycle while ID "submit" appears in the code?

Comment: I try that:`If IsObject(oie.Document.getelementbyid("submit")) Then
MsgBox oie.Document.getelementbyid("submit")
Else: MsgBox "not found"
End If`  and it works for me. Is this correct code to check ID existence?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with handling HTML elements but maybe something like this may get the job done for you?

```
Dim hElement as variant 'Declare it as the actual object name unlike what I've done, if you're using early binding'

On error resume next
Set hElement =
oie.Document.getelementbyid("submit")
On error goto 0

If not (hElement is nothing) then
```

Alternatively, maybe you could loop through the collection of HTML elements on the page and check their ID/some other property that is unique to the 'Submit' element you're looking for?

Something like:

```
Dim hElement as variant
Dim SubmitExists as boolean
SubmitExists = false

For each hElement in oie.document.HTMLelements

SubmitExists = (hElement.ID = "Submit")

Next hElement
```

I'm not saying there will be a collection called 'HTMLelements' and an element property called 'ID' (I made them up as an example to demonstrate the principle). Best place to check actual name of collection and properties would be Microsoft's documentation or Object explorer.